# how to disable a row of listview in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView, each row of it is made up of a TextView and a Button.

When clicking the button, an alert dialog is displayed asking "are you sure you want to disable this item?", and If someone select the button "Yes", the TextView and the Button will be disabled.

My code is as above. As a result, the TextView and the Button are properly disabled, but when I scroll down and up the ListView, these items will be enabled again.

How could I solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
private class QuestionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public QuestionAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] strings) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder") @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout_edit_sample_question, parent, false);

        TextView txt_question = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_question);
        txt_question.setText(qText[position]);

        final int pos = position;

        Button btn_delete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
        btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                DeleteDialog(context, pos, row);
            }
        });

        return row;
    }
}

private void DeleteDialog(final Context context, final int pos, final View row) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialog.setMessage("are you sure you want to disable this item?");

    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_question)).setEnabled(false);
            ((Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete)).setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Use a `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`. This is a know issue, and RV solves it. If this solved your question, inform me so I can post this as an answer.

Comment: Here you need to maintain a boolean array for enabled and disabled item in the array and in the getView method need to check for the same, otherwise it will not be consistent in `ListView` or in `RecyclerView` also.

Comment: Recycler view might not fix your issues, as this is not really a problem- Your views should not care about the data- you are setting something on the view but it is not persistent. Instead of array of strings. You can use more complex data

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of the [`isEnabled` method of BaseAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#isEnabled(int)). Override it and keep a boolean array for enabled indices.

```
boolean[] isEnabled; //initialize somewhere, everything to true

private class QuestionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public QuestionAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] strings) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return isEnabled[position];
    }
}

private void DeleteDialog(final Context context, final int pos, final View row) {

    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            isEnabled[position] = false;
            questionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: This is the best solution. I dont know why manually setting the view's setClickable and even setEnabled doesnt work inside ArrayAdapter's getView()

Answer (score 0):

Use [ViewHolder](https://dzone.com/articles/optimizing-your-listview).

```
static class ViewHolder {
TextView textview;
Button button;
boolean disabled;
}
```

In your array adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(<your layout id>, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        TextView txt_question = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_question);

       holder.textview = txt_question;
    final int pos = position;

    Button btn_delete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);

        holder.disabled = false;
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    final View row = convertView;
    //Set views here
    holder.textview.setText(qText[position]);
     holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            DeleteDialog(context, pos, row);
        }
    });
    //Check for disabled 
    if(disabled){
        //disable the views
    }
    else{
       //enable the views.
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

And set disabled in viewHolder here

```
private void DeleteDialog(final Context context, final int pos, final View row) {
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
alertDialog.setMessage("are you sure you want to disable this item?");

// Setting Positive "Yes" Button
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        holder.disabled = true;
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_question)).setEnabled(false);
        ((Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete)).setEnabled(false);
    }
});

// Setting Negative "NO" Button
alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});

// Showing Alert Message
alertDialog.show();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply use:**

> listview.getChildAt(childPosition).setEnabled(false);

***Example:***

> ```
> if(listview.getChildAt(childPosition).isEnabled())
> {
>     listview.getChildAt(childPosition).setEnabled(false);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your ListView every time inflates new view when you scroll it does not keep old views. You can solve this using holder pattern but the real issue will be still there which is related to your data binding technique.

Use some data Model(POJO) which should have state (enable/disable) and use that state to enable or disable your view. Update Model state from dialog and refresh your adapter by call notifydatasetchanged.